# graphics exception in .net application (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, devexpress, xtragrid

Have you guys met something similar?
Exception type: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
Exception message: The operation completed successfully .
Exception stack trace:

```
------------------------
   at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.CreateCompatibleDIB(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr hpal, Int32 ulWidth, Int32 ulHeight, IntPtr& ppvBits)
   at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.CreateBuffer(IntPtr src, Int32 offsetX, Int32 offsetY, Int32 width, Int32 height)
   at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.AllocBuffer(Graphics targetGraphics, IntPtr targetDC, Rectangle targetRectangle)
   at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.AllocBufferInTempManager(Graphics targetGraphics, IntPtr targetDC, Rectangle targetRectangle)
   at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphicsContext.Allocate(IntPtr targetDC, Rectangle targetRectangle)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.Container.EditorContainer.WndProc(Message& m)
   at DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Everywhere in the app where there is one graphics object used , it is used with using so disposing is enabled.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Some source code would be useful.

Comment: basically it is a large winforms app, and this error appears from time to time in production.  since this cannot be reproduced in testing, i was wondering if this was ever encountered by somebody else and maybe what was the solution or how would you isolate such a thing, if you don't know where it pops out from.

Comment: Do you use background threads for some graphics? i.e. to draw or prepare something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had some similar problems. It sounds like you have some memory leaks in your application. We also had a similar problem and it took us a long time to find out where and what to fix.

In general I can advice you to check, whether the Dispose method of your win form components get invoked when you hide and don't use it any more. But to verify whether you have memory leaks and where to fix them you need a good memory profiler.

At least in our case it solved these win32 exceptions.

Edit:
I just have seen, that dispose is enabled in your case, I still advice you to check every call! We also thought that Dispose gets called, but sometimes it was not!